# ASP TextBox in JavaScript

Tags: c#, java, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I need the client to be able to enter values into an asp TextBox that asks amount of hours they spend doing these activities. The numbers they enter run in javascript. I am having a hard time getting those values into javascript. Then have it run on button click. Thanks for any help. This is what I've got so far:

```
<script runat="server">

    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double work = double.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
        double eat = double.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
        double commute = double.Parse(TextBox3.Text);
        double tv = double.Parse(TextBox4.Text);
        double sleep = double.Parse(TextBox5.Text);
        double total = work + eat + commute + tv + sleep;
        if (total > 24)
        {
            lblmsg.Text = code();
        }
    }
    string code()
    {
        return "Warning: There are only 24 hours in a day!";
    }
</script>
```

Java script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var work = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value;
            var eat = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').value;
            var commute = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox3.ClientID%>').value;
            var tv = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox4.ClientID%>').value;
            var sleep = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox5.ClientID%>').value;
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
              ['Work', work],
              ['Eat', eat],
              ['Commute', commute],
              ['Watch TV', tv],
              ['Sleep', sleep]
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'My Daily Activities',
                is3D: true,
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

    </script>
```

Text Boxes and Button:

```
Work:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="11"/><asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" color="red" BackColor="red" Font-Size="XX-Large"/><br />
          Eat:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" text="2"/><br />
          Commute:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" text="2"/><br />
          Watch TV:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" text="2"/><br />
          Sleep:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" text="7"/><br />
          <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="COMPUTE TIME" OnClick="btn_Click" />
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What exactly doesn't work in the javascript? And when does the script run?

Comment: you are receiving values both in server side and javascript but what is the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing apples and oranges here. You do not need ASP.NET or any other server side language to make basic client-side calculations. jQuery alone can do it anyway with simple HTML textboxes. Just learning using jQuery `val()` and it's enough.